# Build suddenly started to fail with error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryDeferred'

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings, intl-tel-input

I'm using [ng2-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tel-input) in my angular App, so far it was working perfectly but suddenly I started getting an error

```
node_modules/@types/intl-tel-input/index.d.ts(111,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryDeferred'.
```

My `ng2-tel-input` tag is

```
<input type="text" ng2TelInput [ng2TelInputOptions]="mobilePhoneInputOptions"
(ng2TelOutput)="getNumber($event)"
(intlTelInputObject)="telInputObject($event)"
(hasError)="hasError($event)"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedDriver.attributes.mobile_phone"
  (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" />
```

Where default `mobilePhoneInputOptions` is

```
public mobilePhoneInputOptions: any = {
    initialCountry: 'us',
    separateDialCode: true
  };
```

then it changes according to data.

My `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "7.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.9",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.40",
    "@types/intl-tel-input": "^14.0.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.3.0",
    "angular-file": "^0.5.8",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.10",
    "angulartics2": "^2.4.0",
    "aws-api-gateway-client": "^0.2.16",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.386.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "axios-retry": "^2.0.1",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hot-formula-parser": "^2.0.3",
    "intl-tel-input": "^14.0.7",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.5.15",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-mqtt": "^0.1.2",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^1.0.15",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "url-template": "^2.0.8",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.1.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.32",
    "aws-sdk-typescript": "0.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rebuild-node-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^3.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

and my `angular.json` is

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/pure.css",
              "src/assets/css/flexbox.css",
              "src/assets/css/style.css",
              "src/assets/css/modal.css",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.js",
              "node_modules/hot-formula-parser/dist/formula-parser.min.js",
              "src/lib/google-tag-manager/stage.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "stage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-name:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "project-name:build:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project-name:build:production"
            },
            "stage": {
              "browserTarget": "project-name:build:stage"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-name:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.js",
              "node_modules/hot-formula-parser/dist/formula-parser.min.js",
              "src/lib/google-tag-manager/stage.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/material2-app-theme.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "project-name-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "project-name:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "project-name",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this package one other place where it is running perfectly.
So far I've tried

```
npm install intl-tel-input
npm install @types/intl-tel-input
npm install ng2-tel-input
npm install jquery
npm install @types/jquery
```

I have also tried deleting the `node_modules` folder then running `npm i`.
I have also commented the two tags where i was using the package but I am still getting the same errors. I there something I should try? I couldn't find anything related to `JQueryDeferred`.

Comment: Can you please add your module declarations for your component.ts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by deleting the repo from local and again did checkout it from Bitbucket, ran `npm i` and problem disappeared. This is strange because I multiple time pulled code from the repo and deleted then reinstalled *node modules*. I am accepting my answer for now. I don't understand what caused the problem and what I did is not a proper solution so if in case *someone can explain or provide a solution I would choose that as the answer*.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import 'jquery';
```

In your app.component

Comment: Given that we already have an answer that talks about the build environment being the cause, this is an unlikely answer.

Comment: I have the same problem and when I add the import jquery the problem is solved.
If I remove the import the problem reappears

Comment: @Marcell Thanks for your efforts but since I am not able to reproduce the issue now, perhaps an explanation would be better than a fix that I can't test anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and was able to make it go away by installing the type definitions for jquery.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Then importing jquery.

```
import 'jquery';
```